# Django AUTHENTICATION AND AUTHORIZATION groups and permissions want to create verified users

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin-tools

Hi Djangonauts,
                  I am new to Django please forgive any silly mistake in logic or code.

**Intro:**
I am building a web app in which members can write posts on a topic and offer courses on that topic. Example A member can write a blog about doing a wheelie on a bicycle and offer courses on that.

**What I want:**
I want members who want to offer courses to be verified. Example: The member has to fill a form with their details like...
name, address, and photo ID. Plus pay a charge of $9.99 to get verified. After admin (I in this case) checks if everything is good I will approve them.  and then they will be "Verified Members" and be able to offer courses

**What I have so far:** Right now members can offer courses as there is no verified clause

```
class Event(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='seller')
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='course')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    stock = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(35)])
    date = models.DateField()
    time_from = models.TimeField()
    time_to = models.TimeField()
    event_types = (
        ('1', 'Webinar'),
        ('2', 'Actual Meet'),

    )
    event_choice = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=event_types)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('posts:single', kwargs={'username': self.user.username,
                                               'slug': self.post.slug})
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Meet for ' + self.post.title
```

**How I plan to do it:** I was planning to add a group in Django's admin  AUTHENTICATION AND AUTHORIZATION

```
Home › Authentication and Authorization › Groups › Add group
Name: Verified

Permissions: Chosen permissions 
event| event| Can add event
event| event| Can change event
event| event| Can delete event
```

**Now what do I do from here?:** Have I done things right so far, How do I take it from here. Do I create a model called `verified` and add forms.py to have members verified. How do permissions come in the picture.

My monkey patch (not a part of the question, for @Ojas Kale )

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    user_from = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='supporter')
    user_to = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='leader')

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} follows {}'.format(self.user_from, self.user_to)


User.add_to_class('following',
                  models.ManyToManyField('self', through=Contact, related_name='followers', symmetrical=False))
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to go about it is adding a is_verified column in the user. There are various ways for doing this. but extending from abstractUser is probably the most straightforward and suitable in your case, since the class **django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser** provides the full implementation of the default User as an abstract model.

in your app_name.models.py create user class like this.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

in your settingps.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app_name.User'
```

notice how **app_name** is used.

Now you can add as many attributes as you want as well.

By defaul is_verified is set to False, As soon as admin approves (verifies) the user change it to True.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just 1 quick question. Will this change items that I have already attached to my User model. Example I have monkey patched my user model when I made follow/ follower model. Plus username, password, email I have all those. I won't have to make them again correct. I am still reading more about AbstractUser

Comment: AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app_name.User' This line tells django to use this User always. so your monkey patching would not hold. but you can always add those functionalities here as well/

Comment: I have added my monkey patch in the question above. I would hate to lose that. I have gone too far with that model. Is there a way we can address this with groups and permissions Or Any other way

Comment: Can I add is_verified as a patch